# MongoDB $or + sort + sharding = no index used

Tags: mongodb, sorting

Consider the following query, which is a fairly simple use case:

```
db.Transactions.find({
    $or: [
        { "from.addresses" : "name@domain.com" },
        { "to.addresses" : "name@domain.com" }
    ]
}).sort({ "time" : -1 });
```

"from.addresses" and "to.addresses" are indexed fields (arrays). Those indexes aren't compound. There is currently no index on "time".
Note that I'm using sharding on this collection and this might influence the behaviour of the query.

The issues are:

- If I'm sorting on "time" (to paginate correctly the transactions to the user), no index is used and the whole collection is scanned (tens of millions of documents): .explain() => "cursor" : "BasicCursor" on all shards
- If I remove the .sort(), then the indexes are correctly used
- If I remove the $or, then the indexes are correctly used

Is it possible to make MongoDB use the indexes?
I'm currently considering running 2 separate queries (one for each side of the $or) and merging them myself (MUCH faster than the $or behaviour).

Please find below the full .explain() (running on a smaller collection than the real one, running on the real one would take hours):

```
{
        "clusteredType" : "ParallelSort",
        "shards" : {
                "rs/mongo-a:27017,mongo-b:27017" : [
                        {
                                "cursor" : "BasicCursor",
                                "isMultiKey" : false,
                                "n" : 1356,
                                "nscannedObjects" : 45589,
                                "nscanned" : 45589,
                                "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 45589,
                                "nscannedAllPlans" : 45589,
                                "scanAndOrder" : true,
                                "indexOnly" : false,
                                "nYields" : 356,
                                "nChunkSkips" : 8014,
                                "millis" : 44726,
                                "indexBounds" : {

                                },
                                "server" : "mongo-a:27017"
                        }
                ],
                "rs1/mongo-a1:27018,mongo-b1:27018" : [
                        {
                                "cursor" : "BasicCursor",
                                "isMultiKey" : false,
                                "n" : 3435,
                                "nscannedObjects" : 15663,
                                "nscanned" : 15663,
                                "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 15663,
                                "nscannedAllPlans" : 15663,
                                "scanAndOrder" : true,
                                "indexOnly" : false,
                                "nYields" : 4,
                                "nChunkSkips" : 0,
                                "millis" : 505,
                                "indexBounds" : {

                                },
                                "server" : "mongo-a1:27018"
                        }
                ],
                "rs2/mongo-a2:27018,mongo-b2:27018" : [
                        {
                                "cursor" : "BasicCursor",
                                "isMultiKey" : false,
                                "n" : 2208,
                                "nscannedObjects" : 10489,
                                "nscanned" : 10489,
                                "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 10489,
                                "nscannedAllPlans" : 10489,
                                "scanAndOrder" : true,
                                "indexOnly" : false,
                                "nYields" : 2,
                                "nChunkSkips" : 0,
                                "millis" : 329,
                                "indexBounds" : {

                                },
                                "server" : "mongo-a2:27018"
                        }
                ],
                "rs3/mongo-a3:27018,mongo-b3:27018" : [
                        {
                                "cursor" : "BasicCursor",
                                "isMultiKey" : false,
                                "n" : 2249,
                                "nscannedObjects" : 10500,
                                "nscanned" : 10500,
                                "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 10500,
                                "nscannedAllPlans" : 10500,
                                "scanAndOrder" : true,
                                "indexOnly" : false,
                                "nYields" : 7,
                                "nChunkSkips" : 0,
                                "millis" : 439,
                                "indexBounds" : {

                                },
                                "server" : "mongo-a3:27018"
                        }
                ],
                "rs4/mongo-a4:27018,mongo-b4:27018" : [
                        {
                                "cursor" : "BasicCursor",
                                "isMultiKey" : false,
                                "n" : 2251,
                                "nscannedObjects" : 10488,
                                "nscanned" : 10488,
                                "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 10488,
                                "nscannedAllPlans" : 10488,
                                "scanAndOrder" : true,
                                "indexOnly" : false,
                                "nYields" : 4,
                                "nChunkSkips" : 0,
                                "millis" : 336,
                                "indexBounds" : {

                                },
                                "server" : "mongo-a4:27018"
                        }
                ],
                "rs5/mongo-a5:27018,mongo-b5:27018" : [
                        {
                                "cursor" : "BasicCursor",
                                "isMultiKey" : false,
                                "n" : 1175,
                                "nscannedObjects" : 5220,
                                "nscanned" : 5220,
                                "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 5220,
                                "nscannedAllPlans" : 5220,
                                "scanAndOrder" : true,
                                "indexOnly" : false,
                                "nYields" : 2,
                                "nChunkSkips" : 0,
                                "millis" : 376,
                                "indexBounds" : {

                                },
                                "server" : "mongo-a5:27018"
                        }
                ]
        },
        "cursor" : "BasicCursor",
        "n" : 12674,
        "nChunkSkips" : 8014,
        "nYields" : 375,
        "nscanned" : 97949,
        "nscannedAllPlans" : 97949,
        "nscannedObjects" : 97949,
        "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 97949,
        "millisShardTotal" : 46711,
        "millisShardAvg" : 7785,
        "numQueries" : 6,
        "numShards" : 6,
        "millis" : 44939
}
```

Comment: What is the shard key for this collection, and what are the "correct" indexes used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a JIRA you might want to watch: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1205

Comment: Seems to be exactly the problem. Opened in 2010 and still unresolved. Damn, so many issues, I feel so limited!

Comment: @Vincent Indeed it is a pretty serious issue but it should be solved soon

Comment: @Vincent Some say you can hint it in the mean time, it is just that the optimiser doesn't see it

Comment: how do you hint 2 indexes? I tried this but can't found how. Any (other?) workaround for this issue?

Comment: You can't hint 2 indexes, so there may not be a better workaround than running two queries and merging. However, it's worth noting that SERVER-1205 is currently scheduled for the 2.6 production release (planned development/unstable fixVersion is 2.5.5). The query optimizer has actually been rewritten for 2.6, which makes a number of performance improvements (such as this) much more possible.

Comment: @Vincent It seems as though the fix for that might fix a hell of a lot more tickets as well from reading it, I persoally was thinking that you hint one index and the optimiser might have been able to have at least been able to index sort but maybe not, I havent got a way to test

Comment: @Sammaye Just tried to hint on a single index and no, it doesn't work (well, it works, but it only takes the index for the hinted part or the $or, so still need a full scan for the other part, so no performance improvement). I used the solution where I combine the two $or parts myself, by I really hate this.

Comment: @Vincent worth a try :( Well 2.6 is due out soon!

Comment: This is the third major bug I encounter with MongoDB in like 1 month (and I don't even speak about extreme slowness):
https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-5931 https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-826 and https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1205 ; I should have chosen another database...

Comment: @Vincent though good to note that the 5931 is one that only occurs when using secondary reads, you'll only get that kind of consistency in SQL like envos that do on the spot sharding and replication, though those envos come with a tonne of problems, hence why MongoDB goes the alternate route.